# single-word division algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, embedded

I develop software for embedded platform and need a single-word division algorithm.

The problem is as follows: 
given a large integer represented by a sequence of 32-bit words (can be many),
we need to divide it by another 32-bit word, i.e. compute the quotient (also large integer)
and the remainder (32-bits).

Certainly, If I were developing this algorithm on x86, I could simply take GNU MP 
but this library is way too large for embdedde platform. Furthermore, our processor
does not have hardware integer divider (integer division is performed in the software).
However the processor has quite fast FPU, so the trick is to use floating-point arithmetic wherever possible.

Any ideas how to implement this ?

Comment: Is simple restoring division good enough?

Comment: Yes just normal division with remainder which works in O(n) time would be enough, no need for asymptotically fast methods.. but I assume binary (radix 2) restoring division operates on single bits which I wish to avoid, ie, better use whole word division instead

Comment: But then where does the whole word division come from - the FPU? There should be 64 bits in the significant of the floats then, or maybe use half-words..

Comment: we have double-precision arithmetic with 53-bit mantissa. I assume we don't need whole 64-bits in mantissa to realize the division since the multiplication of 64-bit integer by 1.0/x in floating-point will produce 32-bit result with appropriate shift. Of course some rounding errors may occur but that's the trick how to do this..

Comment: I don't know, it sounds somewhat unsafe to me. This should work in any case: http://www.hackersdelight.org/HDcode/divmnu.c.txt

Comment: that looks interesting thanks. This is one way to go but still in this case 32-bit hardware will be underutilized..

Comment: Yes.. I don't have anything better to offer though. Perhaps it may be worth taking just the relevant part of GNU MP?

Comment: maybe.. I'll have a look how they do this in GNU MP but I don't think they use floating-point there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this one: the algorithm divides an integer a[0..n-1] by a single word 'c'
using floating-point for 64x32->32 division. The limbs of the quotient 'q' are just printed in a loop, you can save then in an array if you like. Note that you don't need GMP to run the algorithm - I use it just to compare the results.

```
#include <gmp.h>

// divides a multi-precision integer a[0..n-1] by a single word c
void div_by_limb(const unsigned *a, unsigned n, unsigned c) {

  typedef unsigned long long uint64;
  unsigned c_norm = c, sh = 0;
  while((c_norm & 0xC0000000) == 0) { // make sure the 2 MSB are set
     c_norm <<= 1; sh++;
  }
  // precompute the inverse of 'c'
   double inv1 = 1.0 / (double)c_norm, inv2 = 1.0 / (double)c;
   unsigned i, r = 0;

   printf("\nquotient: "); // quotient is printed in a loop
   for(i = n - 1; (int)i >= 0; i--) { // start from the most significant digit
      unsigned u1 = r, u0 = a[i];
      union {
        struct { unsigned u0, u1; };
        uint64 x;
      } s = {u0, u1}; // treat [u1, u0] as 64-bit int
      // divide a 2-word number [u1, u0] by 'c_norm' using floating-point
      unsigned q = floor((double)s.x * inv1), q2;
      r = u0 - q * c_norm;
      // divide again: this time by 'c'
      q2 = floor((double)r * inv2);

      q = (q << sh) + q2; // reconstruct the quotient
      printf("%x", q);
  }

  r %= c; // adjust the residue after normalization
  printf("; residue: %x\n", r);
}

int main() {
  mpz_t z, quo, rem;
  mpz_init(z); // this is a dividend
  mpz_set_str(z, "9999999999999999999999999999999", 10);
  unsigned div = 9; // this is a divisor
  div_by_limb((unsigned *)z->_mp_d, mpz_size(z), div);
  mpz_init(quo); mpz_init(rem);
  mpz_tdiv_qr_ui(quo, rem, z, div); // divide 'z' by 'div'
  gmp_printf("compare: Quo: %Zx; Rem %Zx\n", quo, rem);
  mpz_clear(quo);
  mpz_clear(rem);
  mpz_clear(z);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: I ran your program on x86 Linux with gmp support, looks like it works fine. Though it took me some time to realize the logic. As far as I understand, you perform 2 double-precision multiplications to realize 64/32->32 bit division since mantissa rounding can screw things up.. cool trick, thanks.. and it does not use division in the main loop. BTW why do you shift c_norm to the left at the begining ? is it to avoid overflow in the division ?

Comment: you are right, I use c_norm to prevent overflow: for instance while dividing 2^63 by 3, the result would exceed 32-bits. Instead I will divide 2^63 by 3*2^30 and later fix the quotient and remainder

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic optimization. Instead of dividing by `D`, multiply by `0x100000000/D` and then divide by `0x100000000`. The latter is just a wordshift, i.e. trivial. Calculating the multiplier is a bit harder, but not a lot.

See also [this detailed article](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html) for a far more detailed background.

Comment: thanks for the article, I learned something. Though if I understand it correctly, to perform 64/32->32 base case division, we would have to multiply a 64-bit integer by a fixed-point number 2^32/D. Seems that this would require a pair of 32x32->64 multiplications which I can only get through inline assembler ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a look-up table and [Newton Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) successive approximation is the canonical choice used by hardware designers (who generally can't afford the gates for a full hardware divide). You get to choose the trade off the between accuracy and execution time.

Comment: @Marco: as I said we don't have hardware integer divider but we DO have quite fast floating-point arithmetic, thus not utilizing it would be stupid. Using iterative algorithm probably is not better then just using radix 2 restoring division algorithm

Comment: Newton Raphson avoids hardware divide - only multiply and subtract (and a LUT) are required.

Comment: yes but how many iterations you need to perform for 64/32->32 division ? this is a base case for single-word division algorithm. Furthermore, using Newton Raphson in double-precision for 64-bit dividend, we again run into problems with rounding since dp mantissa is 53 bits long